# PHP/CakePHP : Update ACOS table?

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, acl

I have created a controllers called user_controller in my cakephp app. After I've run the command : `cake acl create aco root controllers` for filling the ACOs table with my controller.

But now I've created a new method inside my user_controller and I want to update my ACOs table. Is there anyway to proceed using the cake console ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add an aco for the action `my_action` for the `UsersController`

```
cake acl create aco Users my_action
```

To add an aco for a new controller (e.g. for `PostsController`)

```
cake acl create aco controllers Posts
```

For a way to update your aco table automatically after you add new controllers and actions, [check out this aco_sync shell](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/generate-aco-records-for-your-controllers-and-actions-with-acosyncshell)